# Makefile: Ensuring ordering of optional dependencies

Tags: make

I'm writing a makefile for working with a microcontroller.

Among various PHONY targets, are:

- build - builds the project
- flash - flashes the MCU
- serial - opens Minicom serial interface

None of these strictly depends on the other - e.g. I can open serial without rebuilding or reflashing.

BUT, if the other targets are also specified (e.g. `make flash serial`), then a certain ordering needs to be respected (build before flashing, flash before opening serial).

Make is running with concurrency enabled (`-j`) and I don't want to change this.

How do I define optional-dependencies, to ensure ordering of targets, without requiring those dependencies to be checked/updated each time unless requested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is written for GNU Make, I'm not aware of whether MAKECMDGOALS is GNU-only or POSIX.

The targets Make is explicitly asked to build are in the `MAKECMDGOALS` variable.

We can filter this to define optional-dependencies, for ordering purposes:

```
after = $(filter $(strip $1), $(MAKECMDGOALS))

post_build = $(call after, build)
post_flash = $(call after, flash) $(post_build)

...

.PHONY: build flash serial debug

...

flash: | $(post_build)
        st-flash ...

serial: | $(post_flash)
        minicom ...

debug: | $(post_flash)
        $(GDB) ...
```

That way:

- `make build` will build the project
- `make flash` will flash the MCU with the current build
- `make serial` will open the serial interface
- `make flash serial` (or vice-versa) will flash the MCU, then open the serial interface.
- `make build flash` will build the project then flash the MCU.
- `make build flash serial` (in any order) will first build, then flash, then open the serial interface.